# Open Source Web PDF Viewer?

Tags: php, pdf, google-docs, scribd

Is their any Open Source Web PDF Viewer? 
Which has good api through which I can modify the looks of the viewer?
I had tried the Scribd, Google Docs, FlexPaper , and [this](http://view.samurajdata.se/) also. 
But it is not giving me, as I want.
Then i had downloaded the [shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) but it has not given me information about how to use it? 
**So anyone know good web pdf viewer and it would be great if it offers the customization**

And that should be great if it is in php.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Source Javascript PDF viewer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539879/open-source-javascript-pdf-viewer)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're going to find a PDF viewer that's in PHP. The decoding of the PDF format happens on the client, which means your only options are either relying on the client to do the decoding work for you (Adobe Reader, Google Chrome's built-in reader, OS X's Preview app, etc.), rendering it with Javascript, or figuring out some way to convert the PDF into HTML.

PDFs are so ubiquitous these days, that it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me to want to try to render it for a client; rather, simply tell them that the file they're downloading is a PDF and offer links to either [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) or [Adobe Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/), and let the user view the PDF in whatever app they please.

Answer (score 2):

There is a wonderful pdf viewer which is opensource too. The ui implementation is basic. You will have to work on it. But its awesome.

http://view.samurajdata.se/

Comment: Looks like this software is obsolete... Its source code delivers PHP4 code and HTML code where Johann Sebastian Bach just worked with.

Comment: That means it has to be ported. Or maybe there will be some new ones already. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is also a project from Mozilla called PDF.js.  They're hoping to get it to a point where it's available as part of Firefox.

Get it at: http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/

I've tried it out myself and it works very well.  The only issue is the source JS files are about 1.4mb which is rather large and I couldn't minify them due to some weird coding standards.

Comment: awesome component; does it only work in Firefox? how about other browsers? IE/Chrome/Safari?

Comment: Does for me.  I ended up writing a jQuery plugin around it.  http://dev.funkynerd.com/projects/jquery-pdfdoc