# Open Source Javascript PDF viewer

Tags: javascript, pdf, open-source

Is there any open source Javascript based PDF Viewer available? Any guide to developing this kind of script that renders PDF docs would be helpful.

Comment: I don't want to use the word "impossible", but suffice it to say that what you're looking for is impractical.

Comment: It is possible!

1. use javascript to display a popup telling them to download a reader
2. then use javascript to open the reader download page in a new window?

Comment: Google Docs does this as it is. And you can embed them in web pages. I personally want to integrate this as a feature in my own sites as I've had problems creep in with Embedded Google Docs (mostly user error introduced by people maintaining sites I create).

Comment: You can try this http://bloggerplugnplay.blogspot.in/2013/02/javascript-pdf-readerviewer-to-embed-in.html

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There are some guys at Mozilla working on implementing a PDF reader using HTML5 and JavaScript. It is called [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) and one of the developers just made an interesting [blog post](http://andreasgal.com/2011/06/15/pdf-js/) about the project.

Comment: Github: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js, Demo: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

Comment: Does anyone know how to actually implement this? I'm finding it really hard to work out?? Are there any step by step guides out there?

Comment: `PDF.js v1.0.58 (build: ee545dd)
Message: Unexpected server response (204) while retrieving PDF "http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf".`

Comment: @Osu In case you or anyone else still needs this: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/ this has some useful docs in it, as does their examples stored on the github: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/helloworld (see parent directory to helloworld as well for even more examples)

Answer (score 15):

There is an open source HTML5/javascript reader available called Trapeze though its still in its early stages.

Demo site:
https://brendandahl.github.io/trapeze-reader/demos/

Github page:
https://github.com/brendandahl/trapeze-reader

Disclaimer:
I'm the author.

Comment: The permalink `http://trapeze.xyrka.com/` does not work

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [Google Docs](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html) PDF-viewing widget, if you don't mind having them host the "application" itself.

I had more suggestions, but stack overflow only lets me post one hyperlink as a new user, sorry.

Comment: What about right now?

Answer (score 4):

Well it's not even close to the full spec, but there is a [JavaScript and Canvas based PDF viewer](http://logand.com/sw/wps/index.html) out there.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the HTML5 PDF viewer:

http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/demo/

Comment: The GPL version only displays PDFs with a Flash viewer, and it is needed that the PDFs are compressed. For on the fly compression it is needed to install SWFTools on the server.