# Online PDF viewer

Tags: php, javascript, pdf

Given a PDF, how can I display that on the browser and allow certain user interactions (e.g. zooming, etc.) and programmatic actions (e.g. respond to events triggered within the document, etc.) with it? I'm looking for a library, plugin, etc. I'm using jQuery and PHP. Suggestions?

Comment: And you don't want to just let the user's PDF viewer handle it?

Comment: best use is pdf viewer for browser plugin (ie. google chrome has default built in pdf viewer). Please describe more to clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Source Javascript PDF viewer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539879/open-source-javascript-pdf-viewer)

Comment: @Jared, I want to do the in the browser.

Comment: @pointy, do you know of a non-universal approach?

Comment: You want to do what? Mimic a PDF's layout capabilities with a non-PDF viewer?

Comment: @gajahlemu, I want users to be able to view the PDF, copy the text in the PDF, the paste it elsewhere.

Comment: PDF plugins for browsers do that already. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: as I said earlier you can use pdf viewer browser plugin and at your server side make sure to set `content-disposition` header as `inline`. So the user directly open the pdf in browser instead of downloading it as a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still in Beta

https://github.com/andreasgal/pdf.js

Answer (score 2):

Note that Mozilla's PDF.js project has moved its github repository from

https://github.com/andreasgal/pdf.js

to:

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js