# I want to embed pdf project documentation to page

Tags: html, pdf

I need some service or software that allows to do it like Google Docs does(without downloading .pdf). Is it possible?

Comment: This has ben answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/best-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html

Comment: @SamPlusPlus: Much has changed since the question you cite was asked three years ago. For example, it was asked before pdf.js was released and no answers mention it. pdf.js is definitely the library of choice for this task. The following question cites it, as well as some of the other libraries I mentioned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539879/open-source-javascript-pdf-viewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best bet for JavaScript is [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) ([github here](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)). It's backed by Mozilla, which means it's going to stay open and has great browser support.

That said, there's also [trapeze](http://code.google.com/p/trapeze-reader/), [wps](http://logand.com/sw/wps/index.html), [flexpaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/demo/) and of course [Google Docs](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html) and [Scribd](http://www.scribd.com/).

Answer (score 0):

My favorite solution for this is to use Googles PDF viewer. It can be found at https://docs.google.com/viewer. It will give multiple options for embedding.

Comment: I think Google Docs are not allowed to use this way by EULA